# Is it possible to configure W10 to provide a better environment for someone with poor eyesight

Tags: windows, fonts, accessibility

Is it possible to configure W10 to provide a better environment for someone with poor eyesight. i.e. Change or alter fonts etc., to make reading the screens easier.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a bunch of 'Ease of Access' features. Press Start, and type in 'ease of access', and you'll see a list something like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I Like ...  "Press left Alt + left Shift + Print Screen to turn high contrast on and
off."

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure W10 to provide a better environment for
> someone with poor eyesight

Here is a Windows 10 Screen Shot with some specific features.

[image: Windows 10 Accessibility]

Key are the Magnifier to make text much bigger. This can be very helpful.

Also look at High Contrast to make text stand out more.

There are other settings, but the two above are very key.

Comment: Great. I like Win+ + and Win + - particularly